# Libcurl and HTTP Pipelining

Tags: http, libcurl

Libcurl offers CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION callbacks. That's great until you use pipelining and multistack. How do you correlate the header with the body? Let's say tons of requests and bunch of easy handles cause libcurl to establish multiple connections to the server. Let's assume first response header arrives, and there is a delay in receiving the body. In the mean time, second header shows up along with the body. Does libcurl ensure that the second header is not delivered to the application until first response is complete?
This is important because header needs to be associated with the body. I am in the same predicament even when I don't use HEADERFUNCTION. Even if I use just the WRITEFUNCTION, it could receive the replies out of order in a mixed fashion. So the question is: Does libcurl ensure that the responses are delivered as a whole? If it's a single connection, we can be sure that the response order will follow request order. But **I see libcurl making multiple connections when I use pipeling and multistack.** Let's say 5 connections are made to same server because we are talking about Pipelining here. Response header for Conn1 arrives, Before we get the body from Conn1, we get the ResponseHeader from Conn2. Does LibCurl ensure that the Conn2ResponseHeader is not delivered to the application before BodyFromConn1? Otherwise following code will break.

```
class CEasyHandle
{
CURL*   m_pCurl;
bool    m_bInUse;
};

class CMultiStack
{
public:
CURLM* m_pCurlMulti;
deque<CEasyHandle*>& m_listEasyHandles;
static CEasyHandle* gpCurrentlyReceivingEasyHandle;

CEasyHandle* GetAvailableEasyHandle()
{
    // Iterate through m_listEasyHandles and find one that is currently not added to multistack (m_bInUse)
    // if none free, return NULL
}

bool MakeRequest(const char* pUrl)
{
    CEasyHandle* pEasyHandle = GetAvailableEasyHandle();
    if(!pEasyHandle) pEasyHandle = CreateNewEasyHandleAndAddToList();
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasyHandle->m_pCurl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasyHandle->m_pCurl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, pEasyHandle); // header gets the EasyHandle
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasyHandle->m_pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasyHandle->m_pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this); // body gets MultiStack
    // set options, add to multistack, pEasyHandle->m_bInUse = true;
}

static size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    gpCurrentlyReceivingEasyHandle = (CEasyHandle*)userdata;
    // if no data expected, of course set gpCurrentlyReceivingEasyHandle->m_bInUse = false;
}

static size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    CMultiStack* pThisObj = (CMultiStack*)userdata;
    pThisObj->PerformSomeWork();
    // once complete, gpCurrentlyReceivingEasyHandle->m_bInUse = false;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use case `CEasyHandle` as the user data to the `WRITEFUNCTION`? And store a back-pointer to the `CMultiStack` in each `CEasyHandle` when you create them? Then you can always find any of the pieces you need in the `write_callback`, and you don't need to worry about the order.